# Lenovo ideaPad s10-2 - Boot.ini numproc

Tags: boot, lenovo-laptop

I'm using a *[Lenovo ideaPad s10-2](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/laptops/ideapad/s-series/s10-2)* with *Windows XP Home*. 
What is the default value of **numproc** under Boot.ini? (run >msconfig >boot.ini)